# Cannot overwrite pom maven-surefire-plugin from command line

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, plugins

I have in pom the plugin maven-surefire-plugin with skipTests on true.
However, sometimes I want to run the tests from the command line and I want to overwrite this plugin from command line and to **leave the pom file unchanged.**

I tried

```
mvn install -DskipTests=false
```

but it still skips the tests...

Any idea how I can solve my problem...?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using profile can do the trick. It requires you change the pom file though it gives you the behaviour you want.

Set a property in project element

```
<properties>
  <runtests>false</runtests>
</properties>
```

Now create a profile

```
    <profile>
        <id>run-tests</id>
        <properties>
            <runtests>true</runtests>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

in surefire plugin configuration

```
<skipTests>${runtests}</skipTests>
```

Now run mvn install -P run-tests
This command will activate the profile, thus set the runtests property to true

Answer (score 7):

[Skipping by default](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html#Skipping_by_default) is specifically discussed in the plugin documentation:

> If you want to skip tests by default but want the ability to re-enable
>   tests from the command line, you need to go via a properties section
>   in the pom

In other words use a property for the default:

```
    <configuration>
      <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
    </configuration>
```

Define a property:

```
    <properties>
      <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </properties>
```

Properties can be overridden from the command-line:

```
    mvn install -DskipTests=false
```

Note that the `skipTests` in the command-line above refers to the property, not to the plugin parameter with the same name.

Comment: The property can only be overridden by using this placeholder in pom.xml
The updated ref: https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/skipping-test.html